Accurately positioning labels under steps in an HTML range slider
I'm working to create this:

It has to support labels along a slider that are non-linear e.g. 400K, 500K, 750K, 1M but be visually evenly spaced apart.
I got close with this but I can't get the labels in the middle to space as intended.  The middle label are correctly positioned when there are 3 options, but middle labels are misaligned with the dots when there are 4 or more steps.


    <div id="sliders-container">
      <div id="slider1" class="slider-container" data-title="With 5 options" data-values='{"$500":500,"$1,000":1000,"$2,500":2500,"$5,000":5000,"$10,000":10000}' data-start-value="5000"></div>


      <div id="slider3" class="slider-container" data-title="With 3 options" data-values='{"$50K":50000,"$100K":100000,"$200K":200000}' data-start-value="100000"></div>

      <div id="slider2" class="slider-container" data-title="With 4 options" data-values='{"$50K":50000,"$100K":100000,"$200K":200000, "$1M":1000000}' data-start-value="50000"></div>

    </div>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .slider-container {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        position: relative;
      }

      .slider {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
      }

      .slider-dots {
        top: 6px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      .slider-dots div {
        background-color: #cbcbcb;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .form-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        background: #cbcbcb;
        height: 2px;
      }

      .form-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid purple;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
        background-color: purple;
        margin-top: -0.75rem;
      }

      .dynamic-slider-values span {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .dynamic-slider-values span:first-of-type {
        text-align: left;
      }

      .dynamic-slider-values span:last-of-type {
        text-align: right;
      }

    </style>


    <script>
      function createSliderContainer(sliderData) {
        const container = document.createElement('div');
        container.classList.add('slider-container');

        container.innerHTML = `
        <b>${sliderData.title}</b>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8 col-sm-9">
            <div style="position: relative;">
              <input type="range" min="1" max="1" value="1" class="form-range slider dynamic-slider">
              <div class="slider-dots dynamic-slider-dots"></div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between small dynamic-slider-values"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-select dynamic-value-select"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;

        return container;
      }

      function initializeSlider(sliderContainer, keyValuePairs, startValue) {
        const slider = sliderContainer.querySelector('.dynamic-slider');
        const sliderDots = sliderContainer.querySelector('.dynamic-slider-dots');
        const sliderValues = sliderContainer.querySelector('.dynamic-slider-values');
        const valueSelect = sliderContainer.querySelector('.dynamic-value-select');

        const keys = Object.keys(keyValuePairs); // Extract the labels
        const values = Object.values(keyValuePairs); // Extract the actual values

        // Update the slider max attribute based on the number of values
        slider.max = keys.length;

        // Initialize the select dropdown
        valueSelect.innerHTML = '';
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
          const option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = values[index];
          option.textContent = key;
          valueSelect.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Set the start value for the slider and select dropdown
        const startIndex = values.indexOf(startValue);
        if (startIndex !== -1) {
          slider.value = startIndex + 1;
          valueSelect.value = values[startIndex];
        } else {
          slider.value = 1; // Default to the first value if startValue is not found
          valueSelect.value = values[0];
        }

        // Create dots and value labels
        sliderDots.innerHTML = '';
        sliderValues.innerHTML = '';

        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
          // Create dots
          const dot = document.createElement('div');
          sliderDots.appendChild(dot);

          // Create value labels
          const valueLabel = document.createElement('span');
          valueLabel.textContent = key;
          sliderValues.appendChild(valueLabel);
        });

        // Sync slider with select dropdown
        slider.oninput = function() {
          valueSelect.value = values[this.value - 1];
        };

        // Sync select dropdown with slider
        valueSelect.onchange = function() {
          slider.value = values.indexOf(parseInt(this.value)) + 1;
        };
      }

      function createSliders() {
        const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container');

        sliders.forEach(slider => {
          const title = slider.getAttribute('data-title');
          const keyValuePairs = JSON.parse(slider.getAttribute('data-values'));
          const startValue = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-start-value'), 10);

          const sliderContainer = createSliderContainer({
            title
          });
          slider.appendChild(sliderContainer);
          initializeSlider(sliderContainer, keyValuePairs, startValue);
        });
      }

      // Initialize sliders based on the HTML data attributes
      createSliders();

    </script>




Then the labels should be positioned in relation to the dots. I'd move those spans into the dot divs to start and go from there.

You should run that through the validator and fix your errors to make sure that's not contributing to the problem.

Do you want the left and right values to be centered on their dots or not?

@AHaworth I'm looking for the left and right values to not be centered, because that would cause the ends to stick out wider than the width of the slider.

The suggestion to attach the labels to the dots, worked.  Here's the finished version:


<html>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="comborange-init mb-5" data-values='{"$50K":50000,"$100K":100000,"$200K":200000}'
         data-start-value="100000"></div>

    <div class="comborange-init mb-5" data-values='{"$50K":50000,"$100K":100000,"$200K":200000, "$1M":1000000}'
         data-start-value="50000"></div>

    <div class="comborange-init mb-5"
         data-values='{"$500":500,"$1,000":1000,"$2,500":2500,"$5,000":5000,"$10,000":10000}'
         data-start-value="5000"></div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    .comborange-inner-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .form-range {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .comborange-dots {
        z-index: 0;
        top: 6px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .comborange-dots div {
        background-color: #cbcbcb;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .comborange-dots div span {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        word-break: keep-all;
        text-align: center;
        left: -44px;
        top: 16px;
    }

    .comborange-dots div:first-of-type span {
        text-align: left;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .comborange-dots div:last-of-type span {
        text-align: right;
        left: -88px;
    }


    .form-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        background: #cbcbcb;
        height: 2px;
    }

    .form-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid purple;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
        background-color: purple;
        margin-top: -0.75rem;
    }
</style>


<script>
    function createComborangeContainer(comborangeData) {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.classList.add("row");
        container.classList.add("combo-range");

        container.innerHTML = `
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="comborange-inner-container">
                  <input type="range" min="1" max="1" value="1" class="form-range">
                  <div class="comborange-dots"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-select comborange-dropdown"></select>
              </div>
          `;

        return container;
    }

    function initializeComborange(comborangeContainer, keyValuePairs, startValue) {
        const keys = Object.keys(keyValuePairs);
        const values = Object.values(keyValuePairs);

        // Build the select list; this will be the value that gets submitted in the form
        const dropdown = comborangeContainer.querySelector(".comborange-dropdown");
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = values[index];
            option.textContent = key;
            dropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Build the range for visualization of options
        const comborange = comborangeContainer.querySelector("input[type=range]");
        comborange.max = keys.length;

        // Set the initial value for the comborange and select dropdown
        const startIndex = values.indexOf(startValue);
        if (startIndex !== -1) {
            comborange.value = startIndex + 1;
            dropdown.value = values[startIndex];
        } else {
            comborange.value = 1; // Default to the first value if startValue is not found
            dropdown.value = values[0];
        }

        // Create the dots and labels below each step on the range
        const comborangeDots = comborangeContainer.querySelector(".comborange-dots");
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
            const dot = document.createElement("div");
            comborangeDots.appendChild(dot);

            const valueLabel = document.createElement("span");
            valueLabel.textContent = key;
            dot.appendChild(valueLabel);
        });

        // Sync comborange with select dropdown
        comborange.oninput = function() {
            dropdown.value = values[this.value - 1];
        };

        // Sync select dropdown with comborange
        dropdown.onchange = function() {
            comborange.value = values.indexOf(parseInt(this.value)) + 1;
        };
    }

    function createComboranges() {
        const comboranges = document.querySelectorAll(".comborange-init");

        comboranges.forEach(comborange => {
            const keyValuePairs = JSON.parse(comborange.getAttribute("data-values"));
            const startValue = parseInt(comborange.getAttribute("data-start-value"), 10);
            const comborangeContainer = createComborangeContainer();
            comborange.appendChild(comborangeContainer);
            initializeComborange(comborangeContainer, keyValuePairs, startValue);
        });
    }

    createComboranges();

</script>

</body>

</html>



